# Probability of getting triplet

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

I have 5 numbers

```
1 4 4 4 1
```

So i want to get group of 4. In above given 5 group of numbers exactly one triplet (4, 4, 4) can be selected. Hence, the probability of selecting a 4-equal-triplet is `1/10`.

But i how here is calculating??

I want to calculate same on random `n` numbers but could not found formula.

Comment: I this case there are $5\choose 3$ ways to pick 3 items.  Only one of them is (4,4,4)

Comment: Hmm i tried this @turkeyhundt but not getting answer `1/10`.

Comment: Did you get ${5\choose 3} = 10$ ?  ${5\choose 3} = \frac{5!}{3!2!}=10$

Comment: Ohh got it thanks.

Comment: I edited my last comment.  with the formula for how many combinations of 3 can be picked from 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you get ${5\choose 3} = 10$ ?

${5\choose 3} = \frac{5!}{3!2!}=10$

Comment: One more thing. Can you please explain if total numbers are `10`. Following series `1 4 4 4 2 5 4 5 4 4` what would be answer?

Comment: To get a triplet of (4,4,4)?

Comment: Ya ya exactly to get (4, 4, 4) as you can see here is 2 (4, 4, 4) present so answer should be `2/10` is this correct?

Comment: At first glance, there are $10 \choose 3$ total ways to pick a triplet and $6\choose 3$ ways to pick a (4,4,4) from the 6 fours.  So $\frac{20}{120}$ would be the probability

Comment: You can look up some basic lessons on Combinations and Permutations for some explanations on how this stuff is worked out.

Comment: $n \choose r$ is $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}$

Comment: I understood now perfectly thanks